# Windows Identity Foundation for Windows WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, security, authentication

We have a Windows based WPF application supports the user to connect to remote data services. When connecting to the remote services, the user is allowed to perform certain roles. Based on input provided by the remote service, we decide the user access rights and access area.

Given that how Windows Identity Foundation solutions can be used for this purpose? Should the Windows Identity Foundation must be used as part of the Service or Windows client?

Any insightful answers would help us to implement authentication and authorization issues in our Windows WPF Application.

Note that the user names are password are used for authentication which need not be windows domain account.

Answer (score 1):

I´m in the same problem right now. I´m researching arround Windows Authorization Manager and it´s evolution (as people says), Windows Identity Foundation...

But I haven´t found something similar to netSqlAzMan, I´m looking for a WIF based tool that allow us to to manage loosely-coupled applicative authorizations having all these authorizations in a relational database, that is what NetSqlAzMan Is but based on WAM (Windows Authorization Manager).

I´ve realized that many people in many projects use NetSqlAzMan to map tasks or operations to a role and that allos roles inheritance or a similar mechanism.

Probably My decition will be NetSqlAzMan instead of WIF.